# Is there any use at all for code to go between </head> and <body>?

Tags: html

I am just trying to clean up my code by removing any unwanted spaces and while doing so I was about to remove the gap between my `</head>` tag and my `<body>`

So it looks like this:

```
</head>
<body>
```

Instead of this:

```
</head>

<body>
```

but as I was about to do so I was wondering if there is any type of code that can benefit from being in between this space? or whether it's a no go area?

Or would it only be acceptable for leaving notes?

Comment: No, not really. Whitespace is usually ignored by parsers anyway. HTML tags are just structure, and as far as I know, there are no structural elements that sit between `<head>` and `<body>`

Comment: Could save a tiny bit of filesize?

Comment: Yeah it will save one or two bytes :P

Comment: 1 byte per linebreak lol!

Comment: And 1 byte per space, if he uses 4 spaces to indent children of `<body>`, he can save 5 bytes per blank line! But that would be a task for a HTML minifier.

Answer (score 7):

It's not valid HTML markup to place any tags directly into the `<html>` element, except for `<head>`, `<body>` and comments.

As for the blank space, it makes no difference. Some people may argue it's more readable to separate them, due to the highly different purpose of both tags, but for parsing, there's no difference. Of course, you may save as much as 5 bytes in ASCII encoding (assuming you indent children of `<body>` with 4 spaces, that would be "space space space space newline"), but that is easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for spaces between html tags. You can format the code, so as to be more readable. You can use and [W3C validato](http://validator.w3.org/)r to test it.